# Prevent TestContext data from being automagically converted

Tags: c#, .net, coded-ui-tests

I am parameterising my test cases by using data read from .csv files. One of the columns in the csv file has simple date values (as regular strings) in US format, eg `mm/dd/yyyy`. When the data is actually read and populated into a `TestContext` however, `TestContext.DataRow["MyDateColumn"]` actually returns a converted `System.DateTime` object, complete with a timestamp of `12:00:00 AM`. I absolutely do not require or want this automatic conversion. How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the type of the MyDateColumn is set to datetime, then it would/should return a datetime object.

Try changing the type of MyDateColumn to be string and see if that does the trick.

**UPDATE**

Change dates in the CSV so that they are "mm/dd/yyyy" instead of mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: How are you generating the CSV? By hand? Export from Excel?

Comment: .csv's are generated by hand, but we can export from Excel if needed. The data is read automatically in the background from the .csv file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624082.aspx

Comment: Are the dates in the CSV as "mm/dd/yyyy" or mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: I'm thinking you are going to have to try and change the datarowcolumn for MyDateColumn in the datarow, but you would have to change the type before the data is loaded.

Comment: Explicitly quoting the dates works, so for example if I have "12/31/2011" instead of 12/31/2011, the conversion does not occur. Can you please have this as an answer; I will accept that one.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Parse(TestContext.DataRow["MyDateColumn"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: Thank you. I already know how convert the DateTime back to a string, and in fact I am using this method currently. I actually wanted to know if I could have the raw string itself, without the framework (needlessly) converting it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this :)

I just put ' before actual data. When I retrieve data, data comes as is. Before using it, I remove ' from data with substring method.

I remember using this technique on excel to make numbers appear as text. It worked for me.

Comment: Pretty close, I put double qoutes around the data. That way I do not have to remove the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I put double qoutes around the data. That gives back strings, without removing the quotes.

```
columnInt, columnString
1, "11.12.89"  
2, "12.12.89"
```